# How are variables of various data types stored in C++(native) binary?

Tags: c++

I started my adventure with C++ one week back. I have read a lot about C++.
I was experimenting with the following:

```
 char * String1 = "abcdefgh";
```

I, then, tried to modify its value in the following way:

```
 String1[2] = 'f';
```

This resulted in an UNHANDLED EXCEPTION.
But the following results in proper execution:

```
 char String2[9]="abcdefgh";

 String2[7]='s';
```

I tried to extract information about the binary generated using above code using DUMPBIN.
DUMPBIN is a Visual Studio Tool. I used the /ALL option to extract every information contained in the binary.

I could see two instances of **"abcdefgh"** in the RAWDATA section. And I understand why.

My questions are as follows:

1) Although both String1 and String2 are essentially pointers to two different instances of the same character sequence, why is the String1 manipulation not a legal one?

2) I know the compiler generates a SYMBOL TABLE for mapping variable names and their values. IS there any tool to visualize the SYMBOL TABLE in Windows OS?

3) If I have an array of integers instead of the character sequence, can it be found in the RAWDATA?

I could also see the following in RAWDATA:

```
Unknown Runtime Check Error.........
 Stack memory around _alloca was corrupted.......
  ....A local variable was used before it was initialized.........
 ....Stack memory was corrupted..
  ........A cast to a smaller data type has caused a loss of data.
  If this was intentional, you should mask the source of the cast with the appropriate bitmask.
```

How do these things get into the binary executable? What is the purpose of having these messages in the binary(which obviously is not readable)?

EDIT:
My question 1) has a word INSTANCES, which is used to mean the following:

The character sequence "abcdefgh" is derived from a set of non-capitalized ENGLISH ALPHABETS, i.e., {a,b,...,y,z}. This sequence is INSTANCIATED twice and stored at two memory locations, say A and B. String1, points to A(assumption) and String2 points to B. There is no conceptual mix-up in the question.

What I wanted to comprehend was the difference in the attributes of the memory locations A and B, i.e., why one of them was immutable.

Comment: I am afraid you have some basic concepts mixed up. "Proper compilation"? - UNHANDLED EXCEPTION is runtime issue, not compilation one. Symbol table? Local variables are often not stored in any symbol table. "String1 and String2 ... pointers to the same .." they are different pointers. If you want to understand inner workings of C++ compiler / execution, you should do your homework first, start with basics and ask question later, as there are many ways how to shoot into your foot with it.

Comment: The OP may have gotten some concepts wrong, but I think this is a perfectly reasonable question, and it's obvious some thought and research went into it.  +1 from me.

Comment: I clearly understand the difference between compilation errors and runtime errors. I also know that the pointers are different but they point to two instances of  the same character sequence.

Comment: The question and answers make one think this is an adventure into C, not C++...

Comment: @msiyer " point to two instances of the same character sequence." The character sequence is the same, but the attributes of the memory storing the character sequence is different. All current answers correctly explain why.

Comment: @msiyer Most often local pointers are stored in registers and registers are not stored in the symbol table by Microsoft compilers. I am afraid more detailed explanation is not possible in the comment space.  Any compiler course or book will probably tell you more (I have no particular to recommend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char string[] = "foo"
```

This allocates a char array, and initializes it with the values {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}. You get "your own" storage for the chars, and you can modify the array.

```
char strptr* = "foo"
```

This allocates a pointer, and sets the value of that pointer to the address of a char array which contains {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}. The pointer is yours to do with as you wish, but the char array is not. In fact, the type of the array is not `char[]`, but `const char[]`, and `strptr` really ought to be declared as `const char*` so that you do not mistakenly attempt to modify the const array.

In the first case, `"foo"` is an array initializer. In the second, `"foo"` is a string literal.

More specific details about exactly where the memory for each situation is located tend to be unspecified by the standard. However, generally speaking, `char string[] = "foo"` allocates a `char` array on the stack, `char strptr* = "foo"` allocates a `char` pointer on the stack and (statically) allocates a `const char` array in the data section of the executable.

Answer (score 5):

Note: all of the code below refers to a scope within a function.

The code below *initializes* a writeable buffer `string2` with data. The compiler generates initialization code to copy from the read-only compiler generated string to this buffer.

```
char string2[] = "abcdefgh";
```

The code below *stores a pointer* to a read-only, compiler-generated string in `string1`. The string's contents are in a read-only section of the executable image. That's why modifying it will fail.

```
char * string1 = "abcdefgh";
```

You can make it work by having `string1` point to a writeable buffer. This can be achieved by copying the string:

```
char * string1 = strdup("abcdefgh");
....
free(string1); // don't forget to free the buffer!
```

Comment: I think you mean `strdup` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: A compiler does _not_ generate code to copy the initialization data.  You're first C++ extract is _static_ initialization (at least if it has static lifetime), and the compiler doesn't generate anything for it.

Comment: James: well, there's no static anywhere in sight, and if you put it inside of a function, there will be generated code. *Only* if it's static, will there be no generated code, and the buffer will be in an initialized data section of the executable.

Comment: @KubaOber Static lifetime doesn't always require the keyword `static`.  All variables at namespace scope have static lifetime.  And as there's no function or class definition in view, it seems reasonable to suppose that the declarations are at namespace scope.

Answer (score 4):

`char * String1 = "abcdefgh";`
In C (and C++) is const, the compiler is allowed to store fixed const data however it likes, it may have a separate DATA segment, it might have completely const program store (in a Harvard architecture)

`char String2[9]="abcdefgh";` 
Allocates a 9 element arrays of chars and just happens to initialise it with some string. You can do what you want with the array. Arrays of any other type would be stored in the same way.

The error messages for some runtime errors are stored in the program data segment(in the same way as your original char* string). Some of them like "this program needs windows" must obviously be in there rather than in the OS because DOS wouldn't know a program needed a later version of Windows.  But I'm not sure why these particular runtime errors aren't created by the OS

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify a string literal.  The type of a string literal is
`char const[]`, and any attempt to modify one is undefined behavior.
And given a statement like:

```
char* s1 = "a litteral";
```

, the compiler really should generate a warning.  The implicit
conversion to non-const here is deprecated, and was only introduced into
the language to avoid breaking existing code (dating from an epoch when
C didn't have `const`).

In the case:

```
char s2[] = "init";
```

, there isn't really a string literal.  The "string literal" is in fact an
initialization specification, and unlike string literals, doesn't appear
anywhere in memory; it is used by the compiler to determine how `s2`
should be initialized, and is the exact the equivalent of:

```
char s2[] = { 'i', 'n', 'i', 't', '\0' };
```

(It is a bit more convenient to write.)

--
A short historical sidelight: early C didn't have `const`.  The type of
a string literal was `char[]`, and modifying it *was* legal.  This lead
to some very horrible code:

```
char* f() { return "abcd"; }

/* ... */
f()[1] = 'x';
```

and the next time you called `f`, it returned `"axcd"`.  A litteral
which doesn't have the value which appears in the source listing is
*not* the way to readable code, and the C standards committee decided
that this was one feature it was better not to keep.

Answer (score 1):

1) As pointed in the c++ standard (2003) (http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38110)

> 1 A  string literal is a  sequence  of    characters surrounded by
>   double quotes, optionally beginning with the   letter L, as in "..."
>   or L"...".  A string literal that does not begin   with  L  is  an 
>   ordinary string literal, also referred to as a narrow   string
>   literal.  An ordinary string literal has type "array of n const
>   char"  and  static storage duration (*basic.stc*), where n is the size
>   of the string as defined below, and  is  initialized  with  the  given
>   characters.   A string literal that begins with L, such as L"asdf", is
>   a wide string literal.  A wide string literal has  type  "array  of  n
>   const wchar_t" and has static storage duration, where n is the size of
>   the string as defined below, and is initialized with the given charac-
>   ters.
>
> 2 Whether  all  string  literals  are  distinct  (that is, are stored
>   in   nonoverlapping objects)  is  implementation-defined.   The 
>   effect  of   attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.

As stated above, it's not illegal, is undefined behavior, so, with VS you get an exception on windows, with g++ you will get a segmentation fault in linux (basically they look alike though)

2) You can use a Disassembly program and check for the data section of the exe file (check this wiki for more info about several exe file structures [x86 Disassembly/Windows Executable Files](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files))

3) Yes, it should be in the .data section of the exe file